# How can I create Samsung's "Fix Now" button with gradient animation in Android Studio

Tags: android, animation, button, gradient

How can I create this awesome button with gradient animation? I attached a GIF.

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

Make a drawable for background and set in on back

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
    android:radius="14dp"
    />
<gradient
    android:angle="45"
    android:centerX="34%"
    android:startColor="#56ab2f"
    android:endColor="#a8e063"
    android:type="linear"
    />
<padding
    android:left="0dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:bottom="0dp"
    />
<size
    android:width="270dp"
    android:height="60dp"
    />
<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#1d5b01"
    />
</shape>
```

Comment: I asked about the animation..not a simple drawable